# How exactly does the Java.reduce function with 3 parameters work?

Tags: java, lambda, mapreduce, java-stream, reduce

I am currently learning about the `java.reduce()`, and I recently came across something while reading up on some of the material and going through videos. I understand that there are 3 ways to use this, however, I am having issues getting the 3 parameter one to work. I was hoping that someone could better explain what is going on with it, and why I'm not getting the results I excepted (the average of a set of MagicNumber objects). Here is an example of what I have so far:

An object, lets call it MagicNumber.java

```
public class MagicNumber{
    Random randomValueGenerator = new Random();
    int number;
    public MagicNumber(){
        this.number = randomValueGenerator.nextInt();
    }
}
```

A random stream containing magic numbers

```
public static Stream<MagicNumber> getNStream(){
    List<MagicNumber> magic = new ArrayList<MagicNumber>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        magic.add(new MagicNumber());
    }
    return magic.stream();
}
```

A function to return the average magic number

```
// This only returns the sum of the magic numbers and not the average
public static double average(){
    Stream<MagicNumbers> magicNumberStream = getNStream();
    return magicNumberStream.reduce(
        0.0, // initial value
        (a,b) -> a + (double)b.number,
        (a,b) -> (a + b)/100
    )
}
```

As the comment suggests, the above only returns the sum of all the magic numbers. While I expect something. So, I don't believe I fully understand the purpose of the 3rd parameter within the `reduce` function. Also, when I write something like the following using 2 parameters:
A function to return the average magic number

```
// This throws an error due to the return type
public static double average(){
    Stream<MagicNumbers> magicNumberStream = getNStream();
    return magicNumberStream.reduce(
        0.0, // initial value
        (a,b) -> (double)(a.number + b.number)/100
    )
}
```

I get the error `Bad return type in lambda expression: double cannot be converted to MagicNumber`. Could someone explain both (A) why these two `average` functions are not working as expected, and (B) how to modify them in order to get the result I'm looking for? I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Where did you get this example ?

Comment: I made it up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the 3rd argument of `reduce()`. That argument is the combiner function, which combines two intermediate results into a single result.

Now, the reason you are failing to compute the average is that in order to compute the average you have to reduce the `Stream` into 2 values - one is the number of elements and the other is their sum. Once you get those two value, you can divide them.

In order for `reduce()` to produce two values, you can use some class that holds two values, such as `SimpleEntry`.

```
public static double average(){
    Stream<MagicNumber> magicNumberStream = getNStream();
    Map.Entry<Integer,Double> sums = 
        magicNumberStream.reduce(
            new SimpleEntry<Integer,Double>(0,0.0), // initial value (number of elements, sum)
            (a,b) -> new SimpleEntry<>(a.getKey()+1,a.getValue()+b.number),
            (a,b) -> new SimpleEntry<>(a.getKey()+b.getKey(),a.getValue()+b.getValue()));
    return sums.getValue()/sums.getKey();
}
```

Comment: Eran, I noticed that in my answer, I still get the correct average even if I remove parallel(). Could you please tell me why that happens ? I can post it as a separate question if you'd like. Thanks. here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554907/6648326

Comment: @MasterJoe2 If you follow the contracts of the Stream methods, the stream should produce the same output regardless of whether it's parallel or sequential. Therefore, removing `parallel()` shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Eran, I had asked a related question. Feel free to answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555563/understanding-java-stream-reduce-parallel-vs-series thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER** - I am a beginner to lambdas and streams in general.

I think [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60542653/6648326) is better. But, i'll add my answer also. If needed, here is a [short tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) on Streams related to this question.

I used a list of chosen integers instead of your "magic numbers". It is the same because the magic numbers are just integers in your example. So we are really just calculating the average of integers. Moreover, it will be easy to test and learn with a list whose numbers we can decide. Once you figure out the lambda part, you can replace the `List<Integer>` with `List<MagicNumber>` and update the code accordingly.

Although it is not needed, I'll use parallel streams to answer your question. The explanation of the code is in comments.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //For example, consider a list of a *series* of numbers in increasing order.
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        int n = numbers.get(numbers.size()-1);//n = 6 is the number of numbers in list.

        double expectedSum = (n * (n + 1))/2;//By mathematical formula for increasing series.

        Double sum = numbers
                //Take a stream of numbers - it could be integers, "magic numbers" or any other number.
                .stream()
                //Split the stream into mini streams and calculate sum of each of mini stream.
                .parallel()
                //Reduce all the numbers in a stream to their sum.
                .reduce(
                        //start with a partial sum of 0.
                0.0,
                //For a stream, calculate the sum of all the numbers.
                (partialSum, nextNumber) -> partialSum + (double) nextNumber,
                //Add the sums of each mini stream.
                (onePartialSum, anotherPartialSum) -> (onePartialSum + anotherPartialSum)
        );

        System.out.println("Sum : expected value = " + expectedSum + ", actual value = " + sum);

        double expectedAverage = expectedSum/numbers.size();
        double average = sum/numbers.size();

        System.out.println("Average : expected value = " + expectedAverage + ", actual value = " + average);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sum : expected value = 21.0, actual value = 21.0
Average : expected value = 3.5, actual value = 3.5
```

Comment: Actually, I think your question itself sort of answers my question too. I was confused about that last parameter in the reduce method.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points that i would like to discuss based on the question that How reduce method with 3 parameters work?
1.if we are not using parallel Stream method then simply reduce method use identity and accumulator,
below is the demonstration of the same,

```
    int length=se.reduce(0,//identity
    //below is the Accumulator that is Bifunctional parameter
    (i,s)->{
        System.out.println("Initial Value= "+i+" with Stream Object="+s+" Addition is ="+(i+s.length()));//extra work to understand the data        
        return i+s.length();},
    //below is the BinaryOperator method which never gets executed in single pipe Stream**strong text**,    
    (a,b)->{
            System.out.println("First Value that passed to combiner = "+a+" Second value ="+b);//never gets called in single stream
        return a+b;});
    System.out.println(length);
```

output

```
Initial Value= 0 with Stream Object=I Addition would be =1
Initial Value= 1 with Stream Object=am Addition would be =3
Initial Value= 3 with Stream Object=The Addition would be =6
Initial Value= 6 with Stream Object=King Addition would be =10
Initial Value= 10 with Stream Object=Of Addition would be =12
Initial Value= 12 with Stream Object=Java Addition would be =16
16
```

In second case where we apply the Parallel Stream, Combiner will get executed,

```
public static int z=0;//need to put outside of public static void main(String[] args);

List<String> ll=List.of("I","am","very","Brave");
    ll.parallelStream().reduce(0,(i,s)->{
        System.out.println("Initial Value= "+i+" with Stream Object="+s+" With Stream Number= "+z++);
        return i+s.length();},(a,b)->{
            System.out.println("First Value that passed to combiner = "+a+" Second value ="+b);
        return a+b;});
System.out.println(Length);
```

after running this we get below output,

```
Initial Value= 0 with Stream Object=very With Stream Number= 0
Initial Value= 0 with Stream Object=am With Stream Number= 1
Initial Value= 0 with Stream Object=I With Stream Number= 2
Initial Value= 0 with Stream Object=Brave With Stream Number= 3
First Value that passed to combiner = 1 Second value =2
First Value that passed to combiner = 4 Second value =5
First Value that passed to combiner = 3 Second value =9
12
```

which clearly shows that identity is just passing 0 value each time,Hence each stream is different and need combiner to combine the result,
Thanks!

Comment: Avoid phrases like "some points that i would like to discuss based on the question" when providing an answer. Discussions should not be part of an answer; use comments ot chat instead.